# Python Format traceback

Tags: python

The goal is to print the traceback from a failed python script. I have referenced a ton of stack articles, but I can not find one tailored to  my needs. The goal is to email the traceback when there is a failure. I can email everything fine, it is just formating said traceback.

To get my traceback:

```
trace = traceback.format_exc()
send_email("Python Failure", trace, "bj@mydomain.com")
```

Email is being run through an html emailing with smtpObj and MIMEMultipart:

```
def send_email(subject, message, receivers):
    sender = "mydomain.com"
    msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["From"] = sender
    msg["To"] = ", ".join(receivers)

    html = """
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <p><b>""" + subject + """</b></p>
            <p>""" + message + """</p>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
    part1 = MIMEText(message, "plain")
    part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")

    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP("thats.not.cheddar")
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
    smtpObj.quit()
```

When I receive the email, the traceback is there but it is all on one line. I was just wondering if anyone could help format a little bit better.

Comment: Wrap the traceback in a `<pre>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Promoting @snakecharmerb's comment to an answer because it worked for me. Wrap the traceback in `<pre>` tags:

```
f"<pre>{traceback.format_exc()}</pre>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `Content-Type` header of `text` then it should display `\n` as line breaks and you won't get everything on one line.

```
def send_email(subject, message, receivers):
    msg = email.message.Message()
    sender = "mydomain.com"
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["From"] = sender
    msg["To"] = ", ".join(receivers)
    msg.add_header('Content-Type', 'text')
    msg.set_payload(message)

    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP("thats.not.cheddar")
    smtpObj.sendmail(msg["From"], msg["To"], msg.as_string())
    smtpObj.quit()
```

Comment: This is also an answer, but the route I took was to just replace the '\n' coming from unix to '<BR>\r\n'